# how to add 2 values?

Tags: f#

I'm attempting to add two values:

`let addition x y = x + y`

I'm getting an absurd type signature:

```
(obj -> obj option) -> int -> obj -> obj
```

[image]

Why is this happening?

Comment: 1) Do you also get a type error when you try to compile and run the code? (if no, it is probably an editor bug) and 2) is this the whole contents of your file, or is there something more?

Comment: If this is part of a larger file try be explicit about the types and see if something else complains, will probably point out the error `let addition (x:int) (y:int) = x + y`

Comment: As an aside, you might want to make the function `inline`, as it will then support all types that have the `(+)` operator, instead of just supporting `int`.  `let inline addition x y = x + y`

Comment: @AaronM.Eshbach why would it implicitly assume that i want an `int->int` signature?

Comment: If you don't make the function `inline`, then the F# compiler has to create one compiled version of your function, and must therefore infer a single type for your function's parameters.  It can do that based on usage, if there is usage, but if not, it will assume `int` as the default for a mathematical operation like `+`.  Marking it `inline` basically means that the body of your function is dropped in-place at the call site, so the type resolution can be inferred for each usage instead.

Comment: @AaronM.Eshbach why wouldnt that be the default behavior any way? What's the purpose of f# allowing to write functions that are NOT `inline`???

Comment: Inlining functions is *not* the default behavior for many reasons, such as making compiled code extremely large (all function-calls would be replaced by the entire body of the function, and every function it calls, etc.).  Instead, function calls are done by pushing the parameters onto the stack and then jumping to the single copy of the function's code.  Since there is only one copy of the function, it must have parameters of a fixed type (the parameters must be a known size in memory).  Therefore, a function like `add` cannot support both `int` and `int64` because they are different sizes.

Comment: @AaronM.Eshbach thank you! got it !